# Writing a Method to a text file

Tags: java

The methods within the my code produce the correct output. However, I'm having trouble taking the output from my methods and writing it out to a textfile. Is there some special function i need to use to accomplish this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class First {

    public static ArrayList BestRouteArray(int[] someintlist) {                   //Sorting method to turn int list into array
        ArrayList<Integer> BestRouteArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 0; index < someintlist.length; index++) {
            BestRouteArray.add(someintlist[index]);
        }
        return BestRouteArray;
    }


    public static void MostEfficientRoute(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

        ArrayList<Integer> hotel = array;
        int[] BestRoute = new int[hotel.size()];                                    //Defining Variables
        int[] Stop = new int[hotel.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < hotel.size(); i++)
        {
            BestRoute[i] = (int) (Math.pow((200 - hotel.get(i)), 2));               //Penalty Calculations
            Stop[i] = 0;                                                            //Stop, to index values
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (BestRoute[j] + Math.pow((200 - (hotel.get(i) - hotel.get(j))), 2) < BestRoute[i])
                {
                    BestRoute[i] = (int) (BestRoute[j] + Math.pow((200 - (hotel.get(i) - hotel.get(j))), 2));
                    Stop[i] = j + 1;
                }

            }

        }

        // Printing values
        ArrayList<Integer> Storage = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = Stop.length-1;
        while(index>=0)
        {
            Storage.add((index + 1));                                    //Loop to get index of Hotel and Penalty Values
            index = Stop[index]-1;

        }
        Collections.reverse(Storage);                                    //Reversing order of Storage
        ArrayList<Integer> StoredValues = BestRouteArray(BestRoute);        //Taking values from best path int list and storing in array list
        if(StoredValues.get(0) != 0){
            StoredValues.add(0, 0);
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> Penalty = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> HotelMarker = new ArrayList<>();             //Initializing Penalty, and hotel maker as arraylist
        ArrayList<Integer> StorageHotel = Storage;                      //Storing Storage values in Storage hotel values to manipulate

        for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++)                         //Using the storage values as an index to pull Penalty values from
        {
            Penalty.add(StoredValues.get(Storage.get(i)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++)                         //Creating new array list to hold storage values -1
        {
            int value = StorageHotel.get(i);
            StorageHotel.set(i, (value - 1));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++)                         //Using the new StorageHotel list as index to pull hotel values from
        {
            HotelMarker.add(hotel.get(StorageHotel.get(i)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++) {                       //Printing the Values for both Markers and Penalty
            System.out.print("Distance: " + HotelMarker.get(i) + " ");
            System.out.println("Total Penalty: " + Penalty.get(i) + " ");
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, java.io.IOException {

        Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Data.txt"));
        ArrayList<Integer> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
        hotels.add(0);
        while (dataFile.hasNextLine()) {
            hotels.add(dataFile.nextInt());
        }
        dataFile.close();
        MostEfficientRoute(hotels);


        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\OutputData.txt", true));
        outputFile.append(MostEfficientRoute(hotels));
        outputFile.append("account1 balance: ");
        outputFile.close();
    }
        }
```

Comment: what is not working..? writing to file? do you have any errors occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function MostEfficientRoute not returning any value.. just void.. so actually you are not writing anything in the file

```
outputFile.append(MostEfficientRoute(hotels));
```

This call is not writing anything
In your function
so instead of

```
System.out.print("Distance: " + HotelMarker.get(i) + " ");
System.out.println("Total Penalty: " + Penalty.get(i) + " ");
```

Declare a string at fuction level, append the above 2 lines to that string and then return that string.. then it should write in file

like

```
 String response = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++) {                       //Printing the Values for both Markers and Penalty
               response  += "Distance: " + HotelMarker.get(i) + " ";
                response += "Total Penalty: " + Penalty.get(i) + " ";
            }

return response ;
```

also change the return type from `void` to `String`

Comment: Quick follow up, how do i print each string to the text file on a separate line?

Comment: no.. better to create the string with all lines and then print in file.. as writing in file is memory intensive process.. you do not want to do it again and again